# Add leading 0 with gsub

Tags: r

I would like to add leading zeros to an alphanumeric string for a total of ten characters. It is possible, however, that there is a space in between the characters.

```
TestID <- c("1b4 7A1")

gsub(" ","0",sprintf("%010s", TestID))
```

This code adds leading zeros, but also replaces the empty space within the string with a zero. Is there a way to add the zeros only in front of the string?

```
# [1] "0001b4 7A1"
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output.  I am guessing that you need `01b4 07A1`

Comment: Isn't `sprintf("%010s", TestID)` alone doing precisely what you are asking for?

Comment: @plannapus `sprintf("%010d", c(1234))` works for integers but not strings

Comment: sure but `sprintf("%010s", TestID)` doesn´t add zeros.

Comment: Ok on a Mac with R 2.14 it did work, but indeed with the online R interpreter it doesn't. My bad.

Comment: @ plannapus Do you have a clue why it doesn´t? My initial thought too was that `sprintf("%010s", TestID)` should work.

Comment: I m looking at the changelogs to see if this behaviour was changed at some point since 2.14. I ll keep you up to date if i see something.

Comment: @rawr FYI I've run into this before, namely that `sprintf` can be different on different platforms., particularly between *nix and windows. Namely, in the docs there is this on zero padding: `For numbers, pad to the field width with leading zeros. For characters, this zero-pads on some platforms and is ignored on others.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `str_pad` from package `stringr` and do:

```
str_pad(TestID, width=10, side="left", pad="0")
```

This gives:

```
> str_pad(TestID, width=10, side="left", pad="0")
[1] "0001b4 7A1"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sub`

```
sub('^', paste(rep(0,3), collapse=''), TestID)
#[1] "0001b4 7A1"
```

If it is to add 0 at the front

```
paste0('000', TestID)
```

Comment: The strings have to be filled up from the front and have varying lengths, so your solution won't work. The   `stringr` suggested by @antoine-sac works fine.

Comment: I was reffering to your gsub solution `gsub('\\b(?=[0-9])', '0', TestID, perl=TRUE)`. Your ´sub´ solutuion works perfectly to, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution for strings of variable lengths could be

```
paste0(paste(rep("0", 10 - nchar(TestID)), collapse=''), TestID)
# [1] "0001b4 7A1"
```

Comment: Note that this would require some changes to be vectorized.

Answer (score 1):

Can also use the `stringi` package.

```
library(stringi)
stri_pad_left(TestID, pad="0", width=10)
# [1] "0001b4 7A1"
```

Comment: Interestingly, `stringr::str_pad` is just a switch on its argument "side", calling `stri_pad_left` if `side=="left"`

Comment: @antoine-sac yes. You're right. `stringi` package is even more powerful than `stringr` package.